# How can I dynamically reference template file in volt template?

Tags: include, phalcon, volt

We know, `{% include header.volt %}` is reference file with name's `header.volt`.

How can I dynamically reference template file in volt template? 
like this:  
           `{% include variable %}`  
           when variable equal `footer.volt`, theen the program will reference file with name's `footer.volt` 
           when variable equal `index.volt`, then the program will reference file with name's `index.volt`...

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if using variables in include will work, but you can always use `partial()` to include your template:

```
{% set partialName = 'footer' %}
{{ partial('partials/'~partialName) }}
```

Comment: Thank you. According to your method, This problem is solved. It's bothered me for a long time.  Thank you very much.