# Volt not including file if path is concatenated

Tags: phalcon, volt

I'm trying to iterate through a Model collection in volt:

```
{% if model.elements|length > 0 %}
    {% for element in model.getElements() %}
        {% include "partials/panels/edit-" ~ element.getType() ~ ".volt" %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

The type can be text or images. If i use the above code, i get the error:

`View '/path/to/phalcon/apps/frontend/views/partials/panels/edit-image.volt' was not found in the views directory`

I'm sure that the file exists, since if i changethe include, it'll work:

```
{% include "partials/panels/edit-image.volt" %}
```

It'll also fail on:

```
{% include "partials/pandels/edit-" ~ "image.volt %}
```

What is the reason that the first version is producing that error?
( I know i could just use ifs.. But theres quite a list of element types later on. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work.

To include [view dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827002/how-can-i-dynamically-reference-template-file-in-volt-template/19832322#19832322) use `partial`:

```
{% if model.elements|length > 0 %}
    {% for element in model.getElements() %}
        {{ partial( "partials/panels/edit-" ~ element.getType() ) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

There is no `'.volt'` since `partial` will add it.

Comment: Works now, thanks. It even was stated correctly in the documentation. I just didnt notice that difference between partial and include before.